# How to remove the left side of this string?

Tags: string, powershell

My string is:

```
$dst = "Folder_1\SubFolder_2\3\4\5"
```

My goal is to have:

```
$dst_OK = "SubFolder_2\3\4\5"
```

I tried use split function like this:

```
$dst_OK = $dst.split("\")[0]
```

but the result is Folder_1 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following regex to remove the left side of the string:

```
$dst_OK = $dst -replace '^.*?\\'
```

However, since it looks like you are dealing with a path, you may consider to using builtin function within the `System.IO.Path` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this snippet:

```
$first, $rest = "Folder_1\SubFolder_2\3\4\5" -split '\\'
$rest = $rest -join '\'
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution :

```
($dst -split "\\", 2)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2

```
$dst.Substring($dst.IndexOf('\')+1)
```